# slapd nsslapd-maxdescriptors

Tags: configuration, openldap

I need to change the maximun file descriptors of my slapd.

I have an ubuntu server 12.04

I read that nsslapd-maxdescriptors is the atribute that I must change for that.

¿ how can I change nsslapd-maxdescriptors ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of your `/etc/default/slapd` file.

```
# Increase max fd for slapd
ulimit -n 8192
```

That file is sourced from `/etc/init.d/slapd` during each run of that script, and changes will affect the daemon.

This was also discussed upstream at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openldap/+bug/632314